# In VSCode how can you "replace in files" without opening every single file to save?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use "find in files" to replace many instances of a string - Visual Studio Code opens every single file for me to save and close. This becomes unwieldy when the amount of files is greater than 10. Is there a way to make vs code just replace, no questions asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a feature request for this problem last year as you can see in here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14554. But, I don't think this feature has been processed or added yet.

The most closest way that you could do is to activate the `files.autosave` feature into `afterDelay` and set the `files.autoSaveDelay` under `1000ms`.

Alternatively, you could try to use unix/linux command like `sed`.

Comment: Feature has been implemented.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the info

Answer (score -1):

**Ctrl+Alt+Enter** will replace all the matches in all the files (a pop up asking you to confirm will appear)

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Enter just does the regular replace-all that opens all the files and waits for me to save them.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't notice that because I have "files.autoSave" set to "onFocusChange"